# Inline Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm have multiple tables and have an option dropdown that loops through them. When I tested the code in http://codepen.io/fernandob/pen/JEJRMW , it all works fine but when adding it in my Wordpress page, it doesn't run. In wordpress i'm using visual composer and in a text block, via the text editor i paste the html code, following this.

```
            <script>
            if (typeof suffixes !== "undefined") {
                suffixes += ",1390152632";
            } else {
                suffixes = "1390152632";
            }
            function  changeCurrency_1390152632() {
               var idx = document.getElementById("id_selected_currency_1390152632").options.selectedIndex;
               var currency = document.getElementById("id_selected_currency_1390152632").options[document.getElementById("id_selected_currency_1390152632").options.selectedIndex].value;
               var currencies = ["EUR", "USD", "GBP"];
               var i, j;
               for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("currency_" + currencies[i]);
                  var cnt = els.length;
                  if (currency == currencies[i]) {
                     for (j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
                         els[j].style.display = "block";
                     }

                     var a = suffixes.split(",");
                     for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                        document.getElementById("id_selected_currency_" + a[j]).options.selectedIndex = idx;
                     }

                  } else {
                     for (j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
                         els[j].style.display = "none";
                     }
                  }
              }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: hi @hopkins-matt yes i believe i found the answer, for some reason, it's not reading the brackets, in the source code it replaces it with it's HTML equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's replace with html code because you are using text block.
Use RawHTML and RawJS elements under the structure tab using visual composer.
HTML code paste in the Raw HTML element and JavaScrip code paste in the Raw JS element.

See also image:

[image]

Hope this answer help you.